# Oracle: update table with object type udt

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, update, plsql, datatypes

I have this Oracle code:

```
Create type address_ty as object( street varchar2(50),city varchar2(50),prov varchar2(50),cap number);

Create type person_ty as object( name varchar2(50), address address_ty);

Create table client (client_id number,person person_ty);

insert into client
values(1,person_ty('pinco pallo',
         address_ty('Boulevard street' ,'torino','to',10100)));
Commit;

select c.client_id,
     c.person.name,
     c.person.address.street,
     c.person.address.city,
     c.person.address.prov,
     c.person.address.cap
from client c;
```

Everything works good.

Now i want to update c.person.address.prov

I tried with:

```
update client
set client.person.address.prov='MI'
where client.client_id=1
```

But i get an error.

**Ora-00904: "client.person.address.prov" invalid identifier.**

How can i update the field prov??

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alias. It is mandatory when updating a table with an object type.
[UPDATE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/UPDATE.htm#SQLRF01708)

> **t_alias**
>
> Specify a correlation name (alias) for the table, view, or subquery to
>   be referenced elsewhere in the statement. **This alias is required if
>   the DML_table_expression_clause references any object type attributes
>   or object type methods.**

```
Create table client (client_id number,person person_ty);

insert into client 
values(1,person_ty('pinco pallo',
         address_ty('Boulevard street' ,'torino','to',10100)));
Commit;

...

update client c
set c.person.address.prov='MI'
where c.client_id=1;

1 row updated.
```

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't imagine it was for this reason. One simple alias and nothing works... Absurd! :))